# Preserving XML comments and processing instructions that occur before the root element

Tags: python, xml-parsing, comments, lxml, processing-instruction

I need to add a new tag and write back to an XML. Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2011, v.4002-->
    <!DOCTYPE reference-configuration-statement PUBLIC "-//Juniper Networks//DTD Jbook Software Guide//EN"
     "file:////cmsxml/IWServer/default/main/TechPubsWorkInProgress/STAGING/bin/dtds/jbook-sw/jbook-sw.dtd">
    <?Pub UDT _nopagebreak _touchup KeepsKeep="yes" KeepsPrev="no" KeepsNext="no" KeepsBoundary="page"?>
    <?Pub UDT _bookmark _target?>
    <?Pub UDT instructions _comment FontColor="red"?>
    <?Pub UDT instructions-DUPLICATE1 _comment FontColor="red"?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_1 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_3 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_2 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT _bookmark-DUPLICATE1 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_4 _target?>
    <?Pub EntList copy trade micro reg plusmn deg middot mdash ndash nbsp
    caret cent check acute frac12 frac13 frac14 frac15 frac16 frac18 frac23
    frac25 frac34 frac35 frac38 frac45 frac56 frac58 frac78 ohm pi sup sup1
    sup2 sup3 rsquo?>
    <?Pub Inc?>
    <root topic-id="25775"
```

Am able to complete the task with etree.

```
path="C:/Users/pshahul/Desktop/Official/Automation/Write_XMl_files/Source/"
            add=(path, Filename)
            myfile=s.join(add)
            try:
                et = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(myfile)
                tree=etree.parse(myfile)
                docinfo=tree.docinfo.encoding
                root=et.getroot()
                elem = root.find('cli-help')
                if elem is None:
                    new_tag=ET.Element("cli-help")
                    new_tag.text=final
                    root.insert(2,new_tag)
                    et.write(myfile,encoding=docinfo, xml_declaration=True)
                else:
                    elem.text=final
                    et.write(myfile,encoding=docinfo, xml_declaration=True)
            except OSError:
                pass
        else:
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

Now, i got the DOCTYPE and XML declaration, but the following are skipped.

```
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2011, v.4002-->
     <?Pub UDT _nopagebreak _touchup KeepsKeep="yes" KeepsPrev="no" KeepsNext="no" KeepsBoundary="page"?>
    <?Pub UDT _bookmark _target?>
    <?Pub UDT instructions _comment FontColor="red"?>
    <?Pub UDT instructions-DUPLICATE1 _comment FontColor="red"?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_1 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_3 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_2 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT _bookmark-DUPLICATE1 _target?>
    <?Pub UDT __target_4 _target?>
    <?Pub EntList copy trade micro reg plusmn deg middot mdash ndash nbsp
    caret cent check acute frac12 frac13 frac14 frac15 frac16 frac18 frac23
    frac25 frac34 frac35 frac38 frac45 frac56 frac58 frac78 ohm pi sup sup1
    sup2 sup3 rsquo?>
    <?Pub Inc?>
```

How do i preserve that? I need those lines back in my XML file. Plus comments. I find the comments missing too.

Comment: You're only posting parts of the code and the error. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details. The indenting in your 1st snippet is wrong (the last `else`). Also, use 4 *SPACE*s when indenting code, not *TAB*s.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have put my entire code here. My questions are 
1. how to preserve DOCTYPE  2. How to change lt; and gt; to < and >

Comment: The question is still not very clear. When we ask for a [mcve], we are not asking for your entire code. We are asking for the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem. You should remove everything that is not needed.

Comment: @mzjn hope my edit clarifies.

Comment: tree.docinfo.doctype and XML_declaration = True preserve a few. But what about the others?

Comment: If you use lxml,  do not use the tag "elementree". It is confusing because there are no import statements in your code and you use this line: `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(myfile)`. On the other hand, `tree.docinfo` is only available in lxml. Can you understand why I keep nagging about providing COMPLETE (but MINIMAL) code?

Comment: Actually I am an idiot. used lxml but wrote using ET. I used the lxml, and it preserved everything. A cosmetic mistake costed me hours. Sorry, and thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) makes it clear that this is not possible:

> **Note**: Not all elements of the XML input will end up as elements of the parsed tree. Currently, this module skips over any XML comments, processing instructions, and document type declarations in the input

What worked out of the box for me was minidom.  Unless the document is very large you're fine to keep it in memory

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom import Node

xml_string = "<?xml version='1.0'?><!--comment--><root><!--inside comment--><child/></root>"
xml_doc = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
for node in xml_doc.getchildNodes:
    if node.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE:
        print("Comment", node.data)
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by OP, the (or *a*) solution here is to utilize lxml as follows, which will preserve comments as well as processing instructions:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
```