# Preserve comments outside the root element of xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml-comments

I am updating the xml file using python xml module and I want to preserve all the comments, using insert_comment variable is preserving the comments inside root element but removing outside/end of the xml file.

Is there any way to save those comments along with inner ones?

Below is the answers I found.

Python 3.8 added the insert_comments argument to TreeBuilder which:

```
class xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder(element_factory=None, *, comment_factory=None, pi_factory=None, insert_comments=False, insert_pis=False)
```

When insert_comments and/or insert_pis is true, comments/pis will be inserted into the tree if they appear within root element the (**but not outside of it)**.

Comment: lxml preserves all comments. Can you use lxml instead of ElementTree? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45223696/407651

Answer (score 1):

As your question tag contains "elementtree", this answer is specific about that.

The solution you are expecting is may not be possible due to default design of  ElementTree `XMLParser`. The parser skips over the comments. Look into below official documented snippet.

> Note that XMLParser skips over comments in the input instead of
> creating comment objects for them. An ElementTree will only contain
> comment nodes if they have been inserted into to the tree using one of
> the Element methods.

Please find the above content in below documentation link.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

search for `xml.etree.ElementTree.Comment` in above link.

Comment: Most comments can be preserved with ElementTree (the OP is clearly aware of this). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561426/407651. The question is about a special case: comments that occur before the start tag of the root element or after the end tag of the root element.

Comment: That's what. It can not be done using Element Tree

Comment: The documentatation that you quoted is not the whole story. Your answer gives the impression that no comments can be preserved, which is not true.

Comment: why -1 in my question?

Comment: Not sure who did it. It's a genuine question